# Too many footnotes

Tags: numbering, footnotes, footmisc

I have a text with about 31000 lines, so it is quite long. There are many footnotes in the text (1 every second line or so). I am using `footmisc` with the option `perpage`.

Halfway through compiling I get a message that the counter is too large and the compile fails.

If I use a subsection of the text it will compile just fine, so it is solely a matter of my text being ginormous.

What can I do? Sorry, I am a total LaTeX newbie.

Comment: The only time the `Counter too large` error message is issued is for counters that use alphabetic or symbolic representations. If your footnotes use numbers, they're not responsible; maybe a long enumerated list with letters as labels?

Comment: If you really want to use an alphabetic representation for your many footnotes, you might benefit from using Heiko Oberdiek's [`alphalph`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) package.

Comment: I do want letters. Many thanks for the suggestion of alphalph. I will see if it fixes my problem. 

The occasions where a page has so many notes that the alphabet once round does not suffice are few. The sentences are numbered too, so there would be a clash of small numbers everywhere if I used numbers as footnote markers